# Which ECMAScript version to choose for TypeScript compiler in Electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, electron

I am currently targeting `es3` by default in my `tsconfig.json` file of my **Electron 5.0.6** project. I get an error message that I have to upgrade to at least `es6` to use the getter/setter functionality of **TypeScript**.

Now I am wondering how I should choose **the right ECMAScript version** for my project. I obviously want to use the newest features of ECMAScript but I don't know how upgrading to a newer version will change the platform support of my project. I still want to support older OS versions and want to know whether upgrading the ECMAScript target version affects this in some way or whether there is some other reason not to upgrade.

Please tell me if I have to add some more information to my question. I appreciate every answer.

Comment: For Electron? ES2016 should be fine.

Comment: Just check what V8 version your electron version uses in the release documentation or [by this code](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3068).

Comment: @Bergi and how does that help me determine the right ECMAScript version? I am unable to find out my V8 version ATM

Comment: In general, V8 supports the latest ECMAScript version out of the box, so feel free to use ES2019 for a recent Electron version. If you're not sure about a certain feature, check whether your V8 version supports it, or what V8 version you would need to get it.

Comment: Electron includes its own browser, so you don't have to worry about users having old and outdated browsers, you certainly don't have to support ES3 (which is from 1999!)

Answer (score 9):

You should target the supported ECMA version for your app. usually, I choose them based on the Chromium, Node and V8 version for a specific electron release.

Electron **5.0.7** uses Node **v12.0.0** and Chromium **73** so its **ES10/ES2019** compatible. Based on these tables.

- [JSON Table of all the information related to an electron version](https://releases.electronjs.org/releases.json)
- [NodeJS(Main Process) ECMA features compatibility list](https://node.green/)
- [Chromium(Render Process) ECMA features compatibility list](https://compat-table.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/)

**Hint:** Sometimes the main and render process support different specs, so always be sure to target the *correct version for each process*.

Comment: Most of these links -- the two Electron-specific links -- don't work anymore.

Comment: Release table:
https://releases.electronjs.org/releases.json

Comment: Render process ECMA feature compatibility list: https://compat-table.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/